# Geting a trend matrix, matlab (Concept)

Tags: matlab

I 'm getting problem with idea for coding. Any help is wellcome.

I have a matrix and I have to show trend .

```
Limit1=30;
limit2=40;
F=[0 ; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0 ; 1; -79; -84; 35 ; 75; 0 ;0 ]
[row1,col1,v1] = find(abs(F)>30)
[row2,col2,v2] = find(abs(F)>40)
```

When I cross Limit1 I need to check also Limit2 and vice vers .

Any idea please

```
%% OutPut=[ row_of_F,Value_crossing_which_limit(Limit1,Limit2), trend (from lower to upper or vice versa] % values are abs – user31177 1 min ago edit
```

%% This should be output

```
 OutPut_=[ '8'     '30'    'GoingDown'
'8'     '40'    'GoingDown'
'9'     '40'    'GoingDown'
'10'    '40'    'Comingup' 
'11'    '30'    'GoingDown'
'11'    '40'    'GoingDown'
'12'    '40'    'Comingup' 
'12'    '30'    'Comingup' ]
```

Comment: How is "coming up" or "going down" defined? What do the indices in the first column of `Output_` correspond to?

Comment: Dear, Wave of water crosses limit of 30, then 40 also, so at 8 we get two values. Now it has crossed 40, next value is 84 less than 79, so trend is stil down, then wave comes up, first crosses 40, then 30, so agian 2 values.

Comment: Dear: in my question as well as comments I have mentioned values are absolute  ' % values are abs'

Comment: Exactly. So how is 84 less than 79? It seems that you consider the sign, and then -84 is really less than -79. But then the values are not absolute... I suggest you explain your example **in your question** line by line and annotate each step, preferably **inside the question itself**. I'm really failing to see your logic here, and it's horrendously difficult to try to follow it through the comments.

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach?

```
% your data
F=[0 ; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0 ; 1; -79; -84; 35 ; 75; 0 ;0];

% growth state
growthstate = [0; sign(diff(F))];

% state relative to the lim1
% true if crossing lim1
lim1=30;
lim1state_p =  [false; diff(F-lim1>0)];
lim1state_n =  [false; diff(F+lim1>0)];
lim1state = lim1state_p | lim1state_n

% the same for lim2
% true if crossing lim2
lim2=40;
lim2state_p =  [false; diff(F-lim2>0)];
lim2state_n =  [false; diff(F+lim2>0)];
lim2state = lim2state_p | lim2state_n;

% decod growth state
s{1}='GoingDown';
s{2}='GoingUp';
decode = @(idx) s{double(idx>0) + 1};

c = {};
for k=1:length(F)
  if lim1state(k)
    c(end+1,:) = {F(k-1), F(k), k, lim1, decode(growthstate(k))};
  end
  if lim2state(k)
    c(end+1,:) = {F(k-1), F(k), k, lim2, decode(growthstate(k))};
  end
end

% show
c
```

I annotated the output of the program.

```
| F(k-1) | F(k) |  k | level |           | reason                 |
|--------+------+----+-------+-----------+------------------------|
|      1 |  -79 |  8 |    30 | GoingDown | cross -30,F(k)<F(k-1)  |
|      1 |  -79 |  8 |    40 | GoingDown | cross -40,F(k)<F(k-1)  |
|    -79 |  -84 |  9 |     - | -         | no crossing            |
|    -84 |   35 | 10 |    30 | GoingUp   | cross -30, F(k)>F(k-1) |
|    -84 |   35 | 10 |    40 | GoingUp   | cross -40, F(k)>F(k-1) |
|     35 |   75 | 11 |    40 | GoingUp   | cross 40, F(k)>F(k-1)  |
|     75 |    0 | 12 |    30 | GoingDown | cross 30, F(k)<F(k-1)  |
|     75 |    0 | 12 |    40 | GoingDown | cross 40, F(k)<F(k-1)  |
```

Comment: @ slitvinov thanx very much, but we can see your output is far away to my Output_. Anyhow thanx again. I must look for some boring for..if loop.